# Divide values in list A by corresponding values in list B

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

> Given these lists:
>
> ```
> A = [6, 8, 12, 17]
> B = [2.0, 0.5, 1.2, 3.33]
> ```
>
> write a python program to calculate and print out the values of the
>   elements of list A divided by the corresponding elements of list B.

How can I do that? I tried this code but I do not get correct output.

```
import math
A = [1, 5, 7, 13]    
B = [2.0, 0.5, 1.2, 3.33]

for a in A:
    print 'a = ',a

for b in B:
    print 'b = ',b

for c in A:
    print 'A/B = ',c/b
print "DONE!"
```

Comment: Next, have you learned about array indexing? Or have you learned `zip`?

Comment: Why are you importing math?

Comment: In Python 2, you may want to force a floating point division (to avoid truncation of the fractional part of the quotient), e.g. `float(a) / b` or `(a + 0.) / b` instead of `a / b`. In your particular example input this is not needed, because either `a` or `b` is a float (in fact, always `b` is a float), and that will make a floating point division happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close until the last loop

```
for c in A:
    print 'A/B = ',c/b
```

makes no sense, as the value of `b` is from the last loop. You have to do

```
for c in range(len(A)):
    print 'A/B = ',A[c]/B[c]
```

which is apt. You can also look at other ways of doing it as in

- `[A[i]/B[i] for i in range(len(A))]`
- `[i/j for i,j in zip(A,B)]`
- `import numpy; numpy.divide(A,B)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner for that:

```
[ a / b for a, b in zip(A, B) ]
```

This returns `[3.0, 16.0, 10.0, 5.1051051051051051]` in your specific example...

Answer (score 1):

Using the zip() function

```
A = [6, 8, 12, 17]
B = [2.0, 0.5, 1.2, 3.33]
for (a,b) in zip(A,B):
    print a/b
```

Output:

```
3.0
16.0
10.0
5.10510510511
```